# Change Node version with NVM before/while running python script

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, bash, nvm

I need to use a specific version of node.js in order to compile a js project from python code. However, the version might change between runs of the python code.

When I try setting the version with os.system like this:

```
os.system(f"/bin/bash -i -c 'nvm use {node_version}'"))
```

The success of the operation is printed out on the console. However, if I check the version afterwards I see that nothing has changed.

I have also tried setting it before running the python in a bash script, both using
`nvm use` and `nvm alias default` but have had no luck so far.

How can I achieve this? I would prefer changing the version just for the python runtime, but also setting the version as default would be ok as long as the correct version is used for the whole duration of the python execution.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I don't know `nvm`, but my guess would be that `nvm use ....` sets the node version only for the shell being executed.